# Converging series in conditional probability

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Let $(A_i)_{i\in N}$ be a sequence of events which converge to an event $A$. Let $(B_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of events which converge an event $B$. Additionally assume $\mathbb{P}(A_i) > 0$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$ and  $\mathbb{P}(B) > 0$.

**Prove:** $\lim\limits_{i\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{P}(A|B_i) = \mathbb{P}(A|B)$

---

**Proof:**
    Either $B_i \subseteq B_{i+1}$ or $B_i  \supseteq B_{i+1}$ is true.

For $B_i \subseteq B_{i+1}$:
    \begin{align*}
 \lim\limits_{i\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{P}(A|B_i) &= \lim\limits_{i\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap B_i)}{\mathbb{P}(B_i)}&\\
 &= \frac{\mathbb{P}\left(A \cap 
 \left(\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}B_i\right)\right)}{\left(\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}B_i\right)}&\\
 &= \frac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)}{\mathbb{P}(B)}&\\
 &=  \mathbb{P}(A|B)&\\
 \end{align*}

For $B_i  \supseteq B_{i+1}$:
    \begin{align*}
 \lim\limits_{i\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{P}(A|B_i) &= \lim\limits_{i\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap B_i)}{\mathbb{P}(B_i)}&\\
 &= \frac{\mathbb{P}\left(A \cap 
  \left(\bigcap_{i\in\mathbb{N}}B_i\right)\right)}{\left(\bigcap_{i\in\mathbb{N}}B_i\right)}&\\
 &= \frac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)}{\mathbb{P}(B)}&\\
 &=  \mathbb{P}(A|B)&\\
 \end{align*}

---

It seems to me, as if I have missed some caveat, but I am not sure. Is it problematic that in some cases of the series $\mathbb{P}(B) = 0$ might be true?

We already proved that $\lim\limits_{i\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{P}(B_i) = \mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}B_i\right)$ for $B_i \subseteq B_{i+1}$ and vice versa.

Comment: Why do you have to talk about the "A" sequence?

Comment: It was part of another task, basically the same one, but with the $A_i$ as sequence instead of the $B_i$ sequence

Comment: Then, would you please simplify your question.

Comment: I am not sure whether it might be important, as the second statement makes a difference between how the two series look. Therefore it might be necessary to infer something from the attributes of the first series. I don't think so, and i wouldn't know how, but again i am also not sure with my proof.

Comment: I don't mind... But you would get more attention if you deleted the unnecessary details about $A$.